# How to populate collection object using left join without duplicates in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

How to populate collection object using left join without duplicates in Linq.

```
public class List1
{
    public string EmpID { get; set; }
    public string EmpName { get; set; }
}

public class List2
{
    public string EmpID { get; set; }
    public string Addr1 { get; set; }
    public string Addr2 { get; set; }
}

List<List1> list1Obj = new List<List1>();
List<List2> list2Obj = new List<List2>();

list1Obj.Add(new List1 { EmpID = "001", EmpName = "EmpName1" });
list1Obj.Add(new List1 { EmpID = "002", EmpName = "EmpName2" });
list1Obj.Add(new List1 { EmpID = "003", EmpName = "EmpName3" });
list1Obj.Add(new List1 { EmpID = "004", EmpName = "EmpName4" });

list2Obj.Add(new List2 { Addr1 = "Addr11", Addr2 = "Addr21", EmpID = "001" });
list2Obj.Add(new List2 { Addr1 = "Addr12", Addr2 = "Addr22", EmpID = "001" });
list2Obj.Add(new List2 { Addr1 = "Addr13", Addr2 = "Addr23", EmpID = "002" });
list2Obj.Add(new List2 { Addr1 = "Addr14", Addr2 = "Addr24", EmpID = "002" });
list2Obj.Add(new List2 { Addr1 = "Addr15", Addr2 = "Addr25", EmpID = "003" });
```

How to populate below `List<Employee>` using linq left join without duplicates?

```
public class Employee
{
    public string EmpID { get; set; }
    public string EmpName { get; set; }
    public List<Address> EmpAddress { get; set; }
}
```

I tried below code. It returns result with duplicate row..

```
var employeeList =
    (from table1 in list1Obj
    join table2 in list2Obj on table1.EmpID equals table2.EmpID into t
    from st in t.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new Employee
    {
        EmpID = table1.EmpID,
        EmpName = table1.EmpName,
        EmpAddress = (from s in list2Obj
                     where s.EmpID == table1.EmpID
                     select new Address { Addr1=s.Addr1, Addr2=s.Addr2}).ToList()

    })
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please show some effort: what have you tried so far and where did you get stuck? Please remember that SO is not a free code writing service.

Comment: var employeeList =
                (from table1 in list1Obj
                join table2 in list2Obj on table1.EmpID equals table2.EmpID into t
                from st in t.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new Employee
                {
                    EmpID = table1.EmpID,
                    EmpName = table1.EmpName,
                    EmpAddress = (from s in list2Obj
                                 where s.EmpID == table1.EmpID
                                 select new Address { Addr1=s.Addr1, Addr2=s.Addr2}).ToList()

                })

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Join` normally duplicates outer records by the count of the matching inner records. What you really need is a [`GroupJoin`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534297(v=vs.110).aspx):

> GroupJoin<TOuter, TInner, TKey, TResult> produces hierarchical results, which means that elements from outer are paired with collections of matching elements from inner. GroupJoin enables you to base your results on a whole set of matches for each element of outer.

```
var employeeList =
    (from e in list1Obj
     join a in list2Obj on e.EmpID equals a.EmpID into aGroup
     select new Employee
     {
         EmpID = e.EmpID,
         EmpName = e.EmpName,
         EmpAddress = 
             (from a in aGroup
              select new Address
              {
                  Addr1 = a.Addr1,
                  Addr2 = a.Addr2,
              }).ToList()
     }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Lambda expression it can be done as below

```
var employeeList2 = list1Obj.GroupJoin(list2Obj, l1 => l1.EmpID, l2 => l2.EmpID, (l1, l2) => new
        {
            l1,
            l2
        }).Select(row => new Employee
        {

            EmpID = row.l1.EmpID,
            EmpName = row.l1.EmpName,
            EmpAddress = row.l2.Select(add => new Address
            {
                Addr1 = add.Addr1,
                Addr2 = add.Addr2
            }).ToList()

        });
```